# How to prevent long running service cause browser to popup Kill / Wait alert?

Tags: javascript, jquery, odata, sapui5

In my application , a ODATA rest service is called which takes long time to execute and return response. This causes the browser to start showing Wait / Kill alert popup again and again till response finally comes.

```
this.getView().setBusy(true); //start showing busy indicator
.
.
.
setTimeout(function() {
    oModel.create('/serviceURL?sap-client='
            + sapClient, requestObj, null, function(
            data, oev) {

    // Success function
        console.log('fffff');

        that.getView().setBusy(false);
        if (data.JsonOut.indexOf("message:") != -1) {
            var arr = data.JsonOut.split("message:");

            sap.m.MessageBox
                    .alert(arr[1].split(",")[0]);
        }

        that.onBindTable();
    }, function(err) {
        // Error function
        that.getView().setBusy(false);
        var errorObj = JSON.parse(err.response.body);

        var sMsgs = errorObj.error.message.value;
        sap.m.MessageBox.alert(sMsgs);

    });
}, 2000);

.
.
// rest of code gets executed 
.
.
```

I have enclosed my request inside setTimeOut() function to make the call asynchronous but still problem persists. How to avoid popup message from showing up ?

Comment: `make the call asynchronous` no, that's not what setTimeout does at all - it's asynchronous with respect to the surrounding code only, does not mean any long running synchronous code is magically asynchronous - looks like you and the OP in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46175164/how-to-disable-async-in-read-sapui5 need to swap code :p you WANT asynchronous, he does not!!

Comment: how to keep browser responsive during duration of service call ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i suggest you to set the fifth param of the oModel.create method to 'true' which will cause the call to be asynchronous (and remove the setTimeOut()).

```
oModel.create('/serviceURL?sap-client='
            + sapClient, requestObj, null, function(
            data, oev) {

    // Success function
        console.log('fffff');

        that.getView().setBusy(false);
        if (data.JsonOut.indexOf("message:") != -1) {
            var arr = data.JsonOut.split("message:");

            sap.m.MessageBox
                    .alert(arr[1].split(",")[0]);
        }

        that.onBindTable();
    }, function(err) {
        // Error function
        that.getView().setBusy(false);
        var errorObj = JSON.parse(err.response.body);

        var sMsgs = errorObj.error.message.value;
        sap.m.MessageBox.alert(sMsgs);

    }, true);
```

Find a hint there, not sure if it's revelent as i couldn't find the javascript API reference.

https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3503659